# use ngIf to reuse a component in case of error 404 , is possible? How to catch the error?

Tags: angular, components, http-status-code-404, angular-ng-if, code-reuse

I have a root component in the app-routin.module.ts declared as HomeComponent, which I reuse in case of unknown route

```
const routes : Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: PrimaryComponent,
  data: { breadcrumb: 'PRIMARY'},
  children: [
    { path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      canActivate: [HomeGuard],
      pathMatch: 'full',
      data: {breadcrumb: 'Start'}
    },
    ....
    ....
    ....
    { path: '**',
      component: HomeComponent,
      data: {breadcrumb: 'Status Error'}
    }
   ]
 }
];
```

this fulfills its function by loading the same component with the breadcrumb changed.
And here comes my doubt. Inside the html of my HomeComponent I have a span that shows a welcome message on the main page and I would like to reuse all the layout and design to just modify that welcome message by an error message with a redirect link to the home.

I understand that it is possible to use a second span with a ngIf that shows the error message I referred to earlier. But, how can I capture the error to generate a condition for the ngIf? or is there some direct method of angular?
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your route some data to recognize the error:

```
{ path: '**',
  component: HomeComponent,
  data: {
    breadcrumb: 'Status Error',
    error: 404
  }
}
```

in your HomeComponent ts:

```
errorView: number;

constructor(private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
      const data = this.activatedroute.snapshot.data;
      if(data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
        this.errorView = data.error;
      }
}
```

in your HomeComponent html:

```
<div *ngIf="errorView === 404">no url matched</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. So I can apply the *ngIf and [hidden] attribute. Great

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the the route data (breadcrumb value) and set your message based on that

```
message = ''; 
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
  this.message = route.snapshot.data['breadcrumb'] === "Status Error" ? "error message" : "welcome to home page";
}
```

and use that message variable in your template

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Comment: thank u. it works, but I want to use *ngIf. Anyway, it's good to know other ways to deal with the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `Angular HttpClient: Interceptors` to identify whether an error occured or more specifically what type of error has occurred. Then create a centralized `service` where you can define a variable whose state you can change depending on whether an error has occurred or not. Then based of this variable in service you can use `*ngIf()` to display error message or welcome message.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand that it is the most correct method, but it is a small correction on another person's old code and I was looking for a simpler solution to not have to dive for all the code that I do not know.Anyway I'll study the way because I'm developing a project of my own and I see it will be very useful. Very kind

Comment: @javascript110899 Glad to help.